# how to calculate a limit?

Tags: calculus

Here is a well-known function:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right) & x\not=0 \\ 0& x=0\end{cases}.$$

How to calculate :

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(t^2+t)-f(t)}{t^2},$$ does it equal zero?

Comment: have you tried power series or taylor expansion on f(x) when x is not 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if $f'(0),f''(0)$ exists or not using standard definition and then apply L'Hopital's Rule.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is the typical example of a function of class $C^\infty$ whose derivatives of any order are zero at $x=0$. This implies easily that your limit is zero too.